# How to read the XML with JS (Google Maps API)

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps

I have tried to look everywhere, but I can't seem to find the answer and can't seem to figure out at all what I'm doing wrong here. The problem at the moment is that var postLink in the JS is not getting the value from the postLink in the XML.

So what I want to do is add markers on Google Maps. All the marker data is stored in a mysql database. According to the Google provided documentation it's faster to convert to use PHP to convert to XML first and than use that for all the variables in JS.

The PHP seems to echo the XML fine, so I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the JS. For completeness I'll post both (for simplicity only up until there is a problem).

JS:

```
downloadUrl('PHP/markerInfoXML.php', function (data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('markers');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function (markerElem) {
        var postLink = markerElem.getAttribute('postLink');
    });
});

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
    }
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
include('connection.php');

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM markerinfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$doc     = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$node    = $doc->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$node    = $doc->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

$newnode->setAttribute("postLink", $row['postLink']);
}


$xmlfile = $doc->savexml();
echo $xmlfile
?>
```

XML output from the PHP:

```
<markers><marker postLink="https://steemit.com/travel/@martibis/when-the-road-calls-1"/></markers>
```

If there is anyone here who can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome!

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: In the JS the var postLink doesn't get any value (I should add that to the post)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('markers');
```

to

```
var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName('marker');
```

The PHP should also better set `header('Content-Type: application/xml');`.

Comment: The s was a typo but setting the header like you stated did the trick, can't believe that was it! Thanks so much, I lost so much time on this!